# change classname of parent span element using javascript

Tags: javascript

how can we change classname of parent span element on click of input radio button.

```html
<label for="L">
     <span class="lbllevel1">
         <span class="label-size">L</span>
          <input id="L" name="size" type="radio" value="L">
      </span>
 </label>
```

I want to add "selected" class to span element which is with class "lbllevel1" on click of radio button.

Basically, i need output as `<span class="lbllevel1 selected">` when radio button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

you can add an event listener to radio button for click event or change event, use `document.getElementById('L')` to get the input, and inside event handler function use `e.currentTarget` to get current clicked input, you can use `.classList +=` to add class to element, something like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('L');
input.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList += ' selected';
})
```

```css
.selected{
background-color:#888888;
}
```

```html
<label for="L">
 <span class="lbllevel1">
     <span class="label-size">L</span>
      <input id="L" name="size" type="radio" value="L">
  </span>
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lInput = document.getElementById("L");
lInput.addEventListener("click", function() {
    lInput.parentNode.classList.add("selected");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the change event of radio by then add parent element with `selected` class if radio is checked:

```
document.querySelector("#L").addEventListener("change", function () {
  // check if radio is checked
  if (this.checked)
  {
     // add .selected class to parent
     this.parentElement.classList.add("selected");
  }
});
```

[working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/7poeaev7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="L">
<span class="lbllevel1">
      <span class="label-size">L</span>
      <input id="L" name="size" onclick="changeAttr(this)" type="radio" 
value="L">
  </span>
</label>

<script>

 function changeAttr(ele)
{
    ele.parentElement.classList.add('newClass');
}

</script>
```

Please see if this is helpful or not :)

Answer (score 0):

> Check through name

```
if($("input:radio[name='Name']").is(":checked")) {
         //write your code         
}
```

> Check through class

```
if($("input:radio[class='className']").is(":checked")) {
     //write your code         
}
```

> Check through data

```
if($("input:radio[data-name='value']").is(":checked")) {
         //write your code         
}
```